# How do I enable scm basic auth and stp basic auth on azure (development) webapp

Tags: paas

I have already navigated through the Azure portal and I can view both options. However, I am uncertain about the precautions I need to consider if I enable these authentications.

I have thoroughly searched through all available resources on the internet, but unfortunately, I have not come across a suitable solution.